# cant pull deal from living social api, unexpected security token error

Tags: jquery, json, api

My getting a unexpected token error when trying to pull the deals from living social api, code below:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $result = $('#container')
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://monocle.livingsocial.com/v2/deals?api-key=8551A250FEB245E5836CDB902C163A6C',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp:"jsonp"
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data)
     $.each(data.deals, function(idx, deal){
        var html = '<div class="dealSmall masonry-brick"><div class="image"><div     class="merchant">' + deal.id + '<img src="' + deal.description + '"/></div></div><div     class="dealDetail"><div class="dealName">' + deal.image + '</div><div class="price">' +     deal.options[0].price.formattedAmount + '</div></div></div>'
        $result.append(html)
    })
});
});//]]>
```

Comment: there's a space in your url ...

Comment: in my code there's no space, fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/mSWL6/2/

you need to set the format as 'jsonp'

```
var $result = $('#container')
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://monocle.livingsocial.com/v2/deals?api-key=8551A250FEB245E5836CDB902C163A6C&format=jsonp',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data)
     $.each(data.deals, function(idx, deal){
        var html = '<div class="dealSmall masonry-brick"><div class="image"><div     class="merchant">' + deal.id + '<img src="' + deal.description + '"/></div></div><div     class="dealDetail"><div class="dealName">' + deal.image + '</div><div class="price">' +     deal.options[0].price.formattedAmount + '</div></div></div>'
        $result.append(html)
    })
});
```

Comment: i definted the datatype as jsonp, did I do it wrong ? was i suppose to leave out the    jsonp="jsonp" ?

Comment: nevermind, i see the attribute you added to the url, thank you so much